# How to call code-behind code from a unordered list item

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, code-behind

```
<ul runat="server" id="ulDrop">
    <li>Update?</li>
    <li>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="yesno" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>YES</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>NO</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </li>
    <li runat="server" id="liDrop" onclick="logout_Click"><span class="ondrop">Logout</span></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to handle the onclick method from the `LI` from code-behind, so I added the following C# code:

```
public void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Response.Redirect("log-in.aspx");
}
```

It keeps giving me an error, that the function cannot be found.

I am looking to clear out all session set in the asp.net page when "Logout" is clicked, not just the text but the entire `LI` and redirect to another page.

Please help me resolve the issue

Comment: I'm not sure if you are in a webforms app or MVC but you need an element that can take an onclick. An anchor or a LinkButton would work, just put that inside the list item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer Marcus's answer (Adding a server control "LinkButton"). But If you would like to keep your LI and still call a server side method, as workaround you could do as follows:

**Add a hidden button to your form.**

```
<asp:button id="btnId" OnClick="logout_Click" style="display:none"></asp:button>
```

**change your LI to**

```
<li id="liDrop" onclick="logout();"><span class="ondrop">Logout</span></li>
```

**Javascript**

```
function logout()
{
   document.getElementById('<%= btnId.ClientID %>').click();
}
```

Comment: It just reloads the page without executing the code-behind :/

Comment: Answer has been updated. Make sure to get the client id for your button.

Comment: I used `CliendIDMode="Static"` and then also assigned a `CssClass` and modified the code and it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `logout_Click` method in your ASP.NET code is run on the server. The `onclick` attribute on the `li` tag refers to a JavaScript function called `logout_Click` that is run on the client.

In order to run the code on the server, you need to do a PostBack to the server. To test this, you can change your ASPX code as follows (this might introduce some design changes that you'd have to fix afterwards):

```
<li id="liDrop">
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
                    OnClick="logout_Click" 
                    Text="LogOut" />
</li>
```

This adds a [LinkButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) control that posts back to the server so that the `logout_Click` method is run.

Answer (score 0):

The li element - even with runat="server" - is still a HTML element. When you use the onclick-Attribute of that element, it will treat it as a call to a client side JavaScript-function (which isn't defined).

The code behind is server side and cannot be executed from HTML elements. You need ASP Elements for that to work.

Comment: I can't nest dropdownlist within dropdownlist unfortunately.

Comment: See the answer of Markus, he explained it in a little more detail.